# How to have a background image size (without affecting the div)?

Tags: html, css

Right now my background image adapts to the screen size. The problem is, when the screen shrinks too much (e.g. mobile) the background image is no longer long enough to fill the div vertically.

So what I did was to assign a value to `width` instead of using `100%`:

```
#content {
  width: 2000px;
}
```

The problem is, the div is no longer responsive, since it has a fixed width.

How to solve this dilemma?

Here's the relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container clearfix">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

#content {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}

#content .container {
  height: 750px;
}
```

And the live site: http://www.m2comm-semi.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two rules

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center; /* bottom, top, etc */
```

should make your background image work properly on every resolution as long as it is big enough to cover f.e. 1900x1200, just give it a shot and let me know if the result is satisfying, bro.